# GitHub Org Members can't push code using desktop

Tags: git, github

I'm the Owner of a Github Organization.

I've created repos using the command line client with SSH.

We have a team called 'Development' with Write access.

The members are having two issues with Git and Github.

Their version of git is from railsinstaller, but they use GitHub for Windows to push changes.

The first issue is when a member is part of the development team and has cloned the repo using the desktop application they cannot push to it because of a rights error? The only way I have managed to workaround this is by temporarily setting them as an Owner (which is not ideal).

The second issue is similar, when a member tries to push to a branch they're getting an authentication error. So far I have not found a workaround for this.

Is there any way of fixing this without having to create an SSH key for every member, or without too much involvement on my part i.e. command line?

Comment: Do they have write access to Github's repository in question? Can you explicitly see them in settings?

Comment: In this case they do have write access. To test this issue I've made them Owners/Admins. Then just having basic write access doesn't seem to do it.